# How to translate SNMP "enterpriseSpecific trap" number to full OID?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm currently using net-snmp `snmptranslate` to translate the EnterpriseOID of
the traps received by my custom coded trap receiver using the following command:

```
snmptranslate -M. -mALL .1.3.6.1.2.1.39.2.2
```

Now, I am receiving SNMP v1 traps with

```
generic = enterpriseSpecific (6)
```

so I need to decode the specific trap number, e.g. 10003 to the 'full numeric' OID.  Is there a way to do this using `snmptranslate`?  I already have the MIB file associated with the traps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can convert an SNMP v1 specific number to OID using combining the enterprise OID, with a 0, followed by the specific trap number, e.g.

EnterpriseOID + '0' + SpecificTrap